# Android Collision Detection?

Tags: java, android, imageview, collision

Here is the code that I use for the moving ImageView:

```
int x=brickimg.getRight()-brickimg.getLeft();
   int y=brickimg.getBottom()-brickimg.getTop();
   final TranslateAnimation translate = new TranslateAnimation(
           Animation.ABSOLUTE,x1, Animation.ABSOLUTE,
           -2000, Animation.ABSOLUTE,0,
           Animation.ABSOLUTE,y);
   translate.setDuration(1200);//speed of the animation
   translate.setFillEnabled(true);
   translate.setFillAfter(true); 
  //brickimg.startAnimation(translate);

//2nd brick animation

  int x1=brickimg2.getRight()-brickimg2.getLeft();
  int y1=brickimg2.getBottom()-brickimg2.getTop();
  final TranslateAnimation secondone = new TranslateAnimation(
          Animation.ABSOLUTE,x1, Animation.ABSOLUTE,
          -2000, Animation.ABSOLUTE,0,
          Animation.ABSOLUTE,y1);
  secondone.setDuration(1200);//speed of the animation
  secondone.setFillEnabled(true);
  secondone.setFillAfter(true);
```

This is for two images. Here is the code that I tried to use for collision detection:

```
Rect rc1 = new Rect();
brickimg.getDrawingRect(rc1);
Rect rc2 = new Rect();
playerimage.getDrawingRect(rc2);
if (rc1.intersect( rc2)) { 
  playerimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

However, the only thing that happens is that playerimage turns invisible when the app starts. It doesn't turn invisible again. One of the images doesn't move, and the other moves across the screen towards the one that doesn't move (using the code I put above). The image that doesn't move turns invisible immediately, and not when the second image touches it. I'm trying to make it so it does something when it touches the moving image. Besides this, I've also tried .getHitRect and I've also tried .intersects instead of .intersect, but none of it works. The moving image is an ImageView, not a sprite. Is there another option?

Comment: In the first translate definition, you are passing in 'x1' instead of 'x'. I would expect it to throw an error since it doesn't look like it's defined yet (unless you're re-defining it)... Is this the exact code that you're using in your program?

Comment: Wow, I didn't even notice that. x1 was a variable that was being used for another part of the program that I didn't post (it doesn't have anything to do with the collisions). Thanks for pointing that out! (I don't think it showed any errors because x1 was already defined as a variable)

Comment: No problem, hope that helps!

Comment: Your code only has a line to remove the visibility of the image, yet you somehow think that your code should magically restore visibility when they images no longer intersect. Code isn't magic, if you want to restore visibility when they no longer intersect, you need to add an 'else' block that actually restores the visibility!